# Removing duplicates in Flex 4 XMLList with filterfunction

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have seen numerous examples on how to remove duplicates in ArrayCollection but I can't seem to transpose this to XMLList. In most ArrayCollection examples, the example compares the key of the array with hasOwnProperty method and return a bool. That's fine, but what would I compare to when using an XMLList? Let's say I have:

```
<fx:XML id="testXML" xmlns="">
   <universe>
      <category cname="cat 1">
         <item iname = "All"/>
         <item iname = "item 1"/>
         <item iname = "item 2"/>
      </category>
      <category cname="cat 2">
         <item iname = "All"/>
         <item iname = "item 3"/>
         <item iname = "item 4"/>
      </category>
   </universe>
</fx:XML>
```

[actionscript]

```
var myList:XMLList = testXML..@iname;
```

will give two occurences of the item "ALL".
I know I might have to convert the XMLList to an XMLListCollection to use the filterFunction (how would I go about doing that - or should I just define myList as an XMLListCollection right from the start). then on to the filterFunction:

```
private function remove Duplicate (item:Object): Boolean
{
   here I don't know how to compare the item to tell me if the object already exist
   or not. I guess I need to compare the item to a copy of the list and see if the
   item has already been seen in the copy of the list. Or is there a clean way to
   do this?
}
```

then all this is passed to a dropDownList:

```
<s:DropDownList id="myDDL" dataProvider="{myList}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [E4x filter function](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_E4X_advanced_filtering-12947.html) you can for example put the key into an `Object` (if the key is a String, otherwise use a dictionary instead of an `Object`) and look if it is already present to build your [XMLList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XMLList.html) :

```
var xml:XML=<universe>
      <category cname="cat 1">
         <item iname="All"/>
         <item iname="item 1"/>
         <item iname="item 2"/>
      </category>
      <category cname="cat 2">
         <item iname="All"/>
         <item iname="item 3"/>
         <item iname="item 4"/>
      </category>
   </universe>

       function filter(xml:XML):XMLList {
        var seen:Object={}
        return xml..@iname.(!seen[valueOf()]&&(seen[valueOf()]=true))
       }

trace( filter(xml)  )
```

Here a live example at wonderfl : http://wonderfl.net/c/10xr

Comment: +1. I like this.  Now, if only we could get that type of functional filtering on every type of collection :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know how to do this is to use [ActionLinq](http://actionlinq.org). This code will take your e4x code and turn it into an `Enumerable`, cast the attributes as strings, make the items in the list distinct and dump it out as an `ArrayCollection`.

```
myList = Enumerable.from(testXML..@iname)
         .cast(String)
         .distinct()
         .toArrayCollection();
```

If you don't want to use ActionLinq, you can implement this using a `Dictionary`:

```
[Bindable]
private var myList:ArrayList;

private function removeDuplicates(data:XMLList):ArrayList {
    var result:ArrayList = new ArrayList();
    var found:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    for each(var item:String in data) {
        if(item in found) {
            continue;
        }

        found[item] = true;
        result.addItem(item);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then when the XML is ready, you can call it:

```
myList = removeDuplicates(testXML..@iname);
```